# Image downsizing while loop, can't get below 400kB no matter how many iterations are run

Tags: swift, uiimage

```
func downsizeImage(image: UIImage) -> Data{
    var imagePointer = image
    let targetDataSize: CGFloat = 256.0 * 256
    var imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, CGFloat(1.0))!
    while (CGFloat(imageData.count) > targetDataSize){
        var newProportion = targetDataSize / CGFloat(imageData.count)
        print("image data size is \(imageData.count)\n")
        imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imagePointer, CGFloat(newProportion))!
        imagePointer = UIImage(data: imageData)!
    }
    return imageData
}
```

> image data size is 6581432
>
> image data size is 391167
>
> image data size is 394974
>
> image data size is 394915
>
> image data size is 394845

Any clue what my problem is?

Comment: Instead of reducing the JPEQ quality below about 60%, it's better reduce the image size (i.e. the number of pixels). For display, the image will then need to be upscaled. But the resulting quality is better.

Comment: BTW: That's more or less what Josh Homann proposes. (downsampling = reducing the number of pixels)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quality parameter to UIImageJPEGRepresentation is not a proportion of image size.  Rather it specifies who lossy the JPG compression can be.  Quality of zero represents the lossiest and smallest size file the algorithm can generate for your data, but it has no guarantee that its going to be a certain size.  The actual size depends on the size and complexity of the image, in terms of color/spatial frequency since thats what the compression algorithm is discarding. If you need to make your image a certain size on disk I suggest you down sample it to a lower resolution and then use a JPG quality setting between 0.4 and 0.6.  Lowe values tend to produce a bunch of artifacts, depending on the type of image you are compressing.

EDIT: add code for downsampling extension to UIImage:

```
    extension UIImage {
        func resize(to proportion: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
            let newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * proportion, height: size.height * proportion)
            return  UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: newSize).image { context in
                self.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: newSize))
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Josh Homann how do I "down sample it to a lower resolution"